# AbstractArgumentFactory for factories that handle multiple argument types

Tags: java, jdbi

As the [JDBI documentation](https://jdbi.org/#_upgrading_from_v2_to_v3) says:

> *AbstractArgumentFactory* is a generic implementation of *ArgumentFactory* for factories that handle a single argument type.

The doc also provide an [implementation example](https://jdbi.org/#_using_the_argumentfactory_interface) for a wrapper class (or a class that exposes only one value).

Is there a way to register in JDBI an ArgumentFactory that handle multiple argument types?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You only need to implement the interface `ArgumentFactory`, which consists of a single method:

```
Optional<Argument> build(Type type, Object value, ConfigRegistry config)
```

In your implementation, you can implement arbitrary logic based on `type`. If your custom argument should not apply, just return `Optional.empty()`.

The same holds for `ArgumentFactory.Preparable` and its method `prepare` that you may want to implement if your logic allows it.

For the example from the documentation, it would look like this

```
public class UUIDArgumentFactory implements ArgumentFactory.Preparable {

  @Override
  public Optional<Function<Object, Argument>> prepare(Type type, ConfigRegistry config) {
    if (type != UUID.class) {
      return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.of(UUIDArgumentFactory::toArgument);
  }

  private static Argument toArgument(Object value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return (position, statement, ctx) -> statement.setNull(position, Types.VARCHAR);
    }
    return (position, statement, ctx) -> statement.setString(position, value.toString());
  }

}
```